# Undefined value returning from REST API

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to fetch data from this API but unfortunately I'm getting some errors. However I do manage to get some success with a different API.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd";

$fgc = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($fgc, true);
$price = $json["price"];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Bitcoin Widget</title>
 </head>
       <body>
       <div id="container">
        <table width ="100%">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" id="blyat"><?php echo $price; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
       </body>
       </html>
```

When I include this API : https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/ltcusd/
it works fine.

But when I add this API: https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd

XAMPP gives me this error :

> Notice: Undefined index: price in C:\xampp\htdocs\BTCWIDGET\indexx.php
>   on line 7

What might cause this error message?

Comment: I have no idea why bitstamp works for you with the code you posted. Imo it should not. For cryptonator you should be fine if you use `$price = $json["ticker"]["price"];` instead of `$price = $json["price"];`

Comment: It would probably be better to include the json in your post. I don't see how your code would work for either of the links you posted. The json returned by www.bitstamp.net has no `price` key anywhere. The json returned by api.cryptonator.com has `price` under `ticker`. The error message makes this pretty clear.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked once I added ["Ticker"] to the $json.

Comment: Would you please let me know how to make the Data Auto refresh?

Comment: @jh1711 Thank you so much, can you please let me know how to auto refresh JSON API.

Answer (score -2):

Is your index file really spelled indexx.php?  You may be setting the variable price before the api is done fetching the data. It's a race condition.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will block until the API responds

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.